# Refresh excel and save the file with date and time prefix using python

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I want to refresh an excel document and save the file with a datetime suffix like `filename_20220706_1554`.

I wrote this following script:

```
import win32com.client
import time
from datetime import datetime
    
print("Refresh_excel function has started")

xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\folder\filename_.xlsx")
wb.RefreshAll()

time.sleep(5)

datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d-%H%M')
print(datestring)

wb.Save(r'C:\folder\filename_{datestring}.xlsx')
xlapp.Quit()
```

But it raises this error:

```
File "C:\Users\untitled0.py", line 12, in <module>
    wb.Save(r'C:\folder\filename_{datestring}.xlsx')

TypeError: Save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `wb.SaveAs(...)` instead of `wb.Save()`

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are passing an incorrect number of arguments.

It looks like you intended to use `f'string with {arguments}'` but instead used `r'string with {arguments}'` which breaks the string replacement logic.

`r''` strings are raw strings, whereas `f''` strings are formatted strings.

However, you cannot use `\N` in formatted strings. You need raw strings for that.

You should probably build the filename in two steps:

```
filename = f'Hourly_NPI_Sales_Report_{datestring}.xlsx'
filepath = os.path.join(r'C:\NPI\', filename)
```

Comment: @maverick, that's because you cannot use `\N` with string formatting. Updated my answer.

Comment: You can use both `f` and `r`, they're not mutually exclusive~

Comment: While you identified a problem, that is certainly not the cause of a `TypeError` for incorrect number of arguments. The path - correct or not - is still one argument

Comment: @Tomerikoo feel free to provide something useful to the discussion then, it's easy to be a critic.